# SEM Model Syntax Given Path Diagram

Tags: statistics, r-lavaan

I am trying to recreate an analysis of mediation using SEM. I have the following path diagram
[image]

It's clear to me that "FM" is related to "EI" through RMR. The indirect effect is 0.25 (0.40 * 0.63) with a "direct effect" of -0.41. However, I am unable to confidently write the model syntax for `lavaan` . How would one write this syntax?

Additionally, what do the double arrows represent (for example, 0.11 between FM and FFM) -- is this the "covariance". Does this impact the paths going from FM to FFM? Lastly, is this mediation model achievable just using an OLS framework? What advantage did SEM provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first recommend reading the method section of the paper that diagram came from because it will give you additional clues about their model that can't always be seen from a path diagram. However, I think the model would look something like this (but check that you get the same coefficient estimates as in the diagram):

```
model <- '
    EI ~ RMR + FM
    RMR ~ FM + FFM + Age + Sex

    FM ~~ FFM
    FM ~~ Age
    FM ~~ Sex
    FFM ~~ Age
    FFM ~~ Sex
    Age ~~ Sex
'
```

The double arrows (indicated by `~~` in the model) represent the covariance of the residuals. You would include these if you think two variables are related beyond what you were able to measure. Whether you include those residual covariances or not will affect the estimated coefficients because in one case you are saying the variables are unrelated beyond the measured variables, and in the other case you are expecting there to be some association.

I dont think this is achievable with regular OLS, although I'm not 100% sure. SEM has the benefit of modelling latent variables (which you dont have), but it also allows for simultaneous estimation of multiple dependent variables (which you do have). Additionally, notice that the model is actually constrained because it is not modelling a path between `Age` and `EI`, for example, and SEM allows for arbitrary constraints that aren't easy to achieve with OLS

Comment: The original authors stated that the model was initiallyt examined through a fully saturated model with 29 parameters. How does one "count" these parameters. Non-significant paths were removed then. Here's a link to the [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41366-018-0059-4) for more context.

Thank you for your input. Still not clear on the residual covariances -- whether these are shown or not have no influence on the paths but the purpose to show them is what then?

Additionally, how is the indirect path from FM (through RMR) calculated? I assume using the := operator.

Comment: Thats a very recent paper, so the simplest thing to do would to be email the corresponding author and ask for their SPSS syntax, would should give you an idea of exactly what they ran in terms of estimated parameters. and yes mediation is done use `:=`

Comment: re: covariances, the authors modeled the residual covariances in their analysis (which is why you see estimated values on those double lines). they could have also chosen to constrain those covariances to 0, and if they did that the other coefficients in the model would be different. so whether you choose to model the covariances WILL affect the paths

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is years old, but I typically use Onyx to draw path diagrams and have it generate the code for lavaan. Not sure how well it handles mediation-
I would double-check it, but in my experience it has worked out well and is easy to do.

Link to Onyx download here: https://onyx-sem.com/

If you draw your path diagram and right-click, there should be an option to generate code for lavaan, OpenMX, etc. You can also change the arrow heads after drawing them to represent covariances.